# What is the proper way to override a method's return type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, overriding, return-type

In the `Point2D` class below, I got the compiler to stop complaining about the following error:

> *Property 'clone' in type 'Vector2D' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Point2D'.*

By supplying a generic of `<T extends Point2D<T>>` to `Point2D` and referencing `T` in the parameter and return types.

This seems very verbose, and I am not sure if this is the proper way of handling this. I tried to search for similar questions, but most of them deal with generic instance values, rather than overriding method return types.

Also, this seems very cumbersome as well:

```
// Point2d#set(number, number)
set(x: number, y: number): T {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  return this as unknown as T
}
```

Here is the complete code below:

#### `types.ts`

```
type Serialized = {
  type: string
}
type NumberPair = [number, number]
type Point2DObject = {
  x: number
  y: number
}
type Point2DSerialized = Serialized & Point2DObject
type Vector2DObject = Point2DObject
type Vector2DArray = NumberPair
type Vector2DSerialized = Serialized & Vector2DObject
type Object2D = Vector2DObject | Point2DObject
type Array2D = Vector2DArray | NumberPair
```

#### `Point2D.ts`

```
class Point2D<T extends Point2D<T>> {
  public x: number
  public y: number

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }

  getClassName(): string {
    return 'Point2D'
  }

  toSerializable(): Point2DSerialized {
    return { type: this.getClassName(), ...this.toObject() }
  }

  toString(): string {
    return JSON.stringify(this.toSerializable())
  }

  toArray(): Array2D {
    return [this.x, this.y]
  }

  toObject(): Object2D {
    return { x: this.x, y: this.y }
  }

  equals(other: Object2D): boolean {
    return other && this.x === other.x && this.y == other.y
  }

  clone(): T {
    return new Point2D(this.x, this.y) as T
  }

  copyFrom(otherVector: T): T {
    return this.set(otherVector.x, otherVector.y)
  }

  copyFromFloats(x: number, y: number): T {
    return this.set(x, y)
  }

  set(x: number, y: number): T {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    return this as unknown as T
  }
}
```

#### `Vector2D.ts`

```
class Vector2D extends Point2D<Vector2D> {
  constructor(x: number = 0, y: number = 0) {
    super(x, y)
  }

  static fromArray(arr: Array2D): Vector2D {
    return new Vector2D(arr[0], arr[1])
  }

  static fromObject(obj: Object2D): Vector2D {
    return new Vector2D(obj.x, obj.y)
  }

  static fromVector(vector: Vector2D): Vector2D {
    return new Vector2D(vector.x, vector.y)
  }

  static zero(): Vector2D {
    return new Vector2D(0, 0)
  }

  /** @override */
  getClassName(): string {
    return 'Vector2D'
  }

  /** @override */
  toSerializable(): Vector2DSerialized {
    return super.toSerializable() /* as Vector2DSerialized */
  }

  /** @override */
  clone(): Vector2D {
    return new Vector2D(this.x, this.y)
  }
}
```

#### Example call

```
new Vector2D().clone() /* is Vector2D */
```

Comment: You could use [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) which is implicitly a generic type of the form you're writing out explicitly.  It looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wX1lJN). Note that you still need some type assertions; `new X() as this` is necessary because `X` might have a subtype `Y` that does *not* override that method, and then `new X()` would not be a valid `Y`.  Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?